# Got an error while running vagrant ssh

Tags: docker, ssh, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have install VM, docker-engine following a book. All command work correctly, no error found there.

But when i run this in terminal

```
vagrant ssh
```

I got this error

```
==> dev: The container is not currently running.
```

I google this and follow several answer from github issue and stackoverflow but can't overcome this error.

N.B: I am fairly new to Vagrant and Docker both

Comment: If you need any others info let me know. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I fixed it by patching [host_machine_port_checker.rb](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/providers/docker/action/host_machine_port_checker.rb) and adding an extra argument I discard in `port_check`:

```
def port_check(discard_this, port)
    host_machine = @machine.provider.host_vm
    host_machine.guest.capability(:port_open_check, port)
end
```

Thanks [Dimitrios Kouzis-Loukas](https://github.com/lookfwd).